# Extending Django User for Permission

Tags: django, permissions, authentication, extend

I just want List user to be under permission , so i just made one custom  model like below

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import  Permission,User

class Mycustomuser(User):
    class Meta:
        permissions = (
            ('users','users'),
            ('view_user', 'View user'),
        )
```

In views i simply called

```
items=Mycustomuser.objects.all()
```

It is returning user id with 4 only.

I did so because i made following permission using django guardian

```
task = MyCustomuser.objects.create()
joe = User.objects.get(username__exact='admin')
assign('view_category', joe, task)
```

Now i want to check that permission whenever MyCustomuser is called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not necessary and also not recommended to extend `User` model. See [Storing additional information about users](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users).

That said, you can create Permissions without setting `permissions` model Meta attribute, see [Programmatically creating permissions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users).

Comment: I dont want to store additional information, i just want CRUD of user under permissions, like John can view user, Tom can create+view user.I have used django guardian for permission stuffs and its working pretty well for custom model,  so i just want to make custom model extending User, but it is not returning all data!!!